# Problem about printing certain rows without using Pandas

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to print out the first 5 rows of the data from sklearn.datasets.load_diabetes. I tried `head()` and `iloc` but it seems not effective. What should I do?

Here is my work

```
# 1. Import dataset about diabetes from the sklearn package: from sklearn import
from sklearn import datasets

# 2. Load the data (use .load_diabetes() function )
df = datasets.load_diabetes()
df

# 3. Print out feature names and target names

# Features Names
x = df.feature_names
x

# Target Names 
y = df.target
y

# 4. Print out the first 5 rows of the data
df.head(5)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in __getattr__(self, key)
    113         try:
--> 114             return self[key]
    115         except KeyError:

KeyError: 'head'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in __getattr__(self, key)
    114             return self[key]
    115         except KeyError:
--> 116             raise AttributeError(key)
    117 
    118     def __setstate__(self, state):

AttributeError: head
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation for `load_diabetes()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_diabetes.html#sklearn.datasets.load_diabetes) it doesn't return a Pandas dataframe by default, so no wonder it doesn't work.

You can apparently do

```
df = datasets.load_diabetes(as_frame=True).data
```

if you want a dataframe.

If you don't want a dataframe, you need to read up on how Numpy array slicing works, since that's what you get by default.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I thank Mr.AKX for giving me a useful hint. I can find my answer:

```
# 1. Import dataset about diabetes from the sklearn package: from sklearn import
from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd

# 2. Load the data (use .load_diabetes() function )
data = datasets.load_diabetes()

# 3. Print out feature names and target names

# Features Names
x = data.feature_names
x

# Target Names 
y = data.target
y

# 4. Print out the first 5 rows of the data
df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)
df.head(5)
```

Comment: How is that consistent with the explicit requirement in your title "*without using Pandas*"? Please edit & update your title accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The method load_diabetes() doesn't return a DataFrame by default but if you are using sklearn 0.23 or higher you can set as_frame parameter to True so it will return a Pd.DataFrame object.

```
df = datasets.load_diabetes(as_frame=True)
```

Then you can call head method and it will show you the first 5 rows, no need to specify 5.

```
print(df.head())
```